# How can I call a function as soon as I go back to the main screen? - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, navigator, materialpageroute

*Hello,*

From the main screen of my app, pressing a button switches to another screen.

```
IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) {
                            return screen2();
                          },
                        ),
                      );
                    },
```

When I am in screen2 and I want to go back or I can press a button.
`Navigator.pop(context);` or press the android back button.

How can I call a function as soon as I go back to the main screen?

*Thank you.*

Answer (score 0):

**From what I understood you want to trigger a function when you go to the previous page!**

So,
Make the main screen as a Stateful widget and then initialize an init state and inside the init state put the function you want to trigger

Such as like this below code

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    FunctionYouWantToTrigger();
  }
```

Comment: I need the main screen to be a stateless widget

Comment: @CastoldiG refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/70996024/13311722 it might help you

Comment: That was what I was looking for.  I also want the same thing to happen when I press the "back" button on Android, do you know how I can do that?